# Названия войн; "рваное" вопросительное предложение

Tags: пунктуация

> Впрочем, здесь никакая война не тема для светских обсуждений. Обычно
>   тут говорят: пока турки не пришли. Или: когда турки ушли. Чаще
>   просто: когда война прекратилась. Но какая? Болгаро-сербская,
>   сербско-болгарская, сербско-турецкая, Первая или Вторая Балканская,
>   Первая или Вторая мировая, Косовская война? – становится ясно только
>   из контекста.

*Но какая – болгаро-сербская, сербско-болгарская, сербско-турецкая, Первая или Вторая Балканская, Первая или Вторая мировая, Косовская война? – становится ясно только из контекста.*

Правильно оформила?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Но какая – **болгаро-сербская, сербско-болгарская, сербско-турецкая, Первая или Вторая Балканская, Первая или Вторая мировая, Косовская война** – становится ясно только из контекста.*

Я думаю, что вопросительный знак не нужен.

Сравнить: *Но какая, Первая или Вторая мировая, становится ясно только из контекста.* У нас же обособление не запятыми, а тире, это  СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

Или: *Но какая – становится ясно только из контекста.*